# How to point to Powershell version 3 from Powershell 4?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am using Powershell v4.

By typing the following command i am able to switch to PowershellV2.

> Powershell -Version 2

But the below is not working. It stays in Powershell v4.

> Powershell -Version 3

how to switch to Powershell v3 from v4? The reason behind is given below.

In our customer environment Powershell v3 will be there and they are not going to migrate to .Net 4.5.2 for this release (it means they can't go to Powershell v4). but in our environment we have upgraded. Now we would like to test our scripts in v3 environment.

Comment: I can confirm this does not work with version 4.0 or version 5.0.

Comment: Only connect item I found was for `-version 2.0` on PowerShell 4.0 (https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/Feedback/Details/1991158) You might want to just submit bug report for this: http://connect.microsoft..com/powershell

Comment: Doesn't look like it's meant to be supported. What specifically are you trying to do that you need to start 3 instead of 4?

Comment: The differences between 3/4 should not be an issue for what you are doing.

Comment: @Matt I have updated the background details. In reality constraints always there unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

I guess this is by design.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847736.aspx

> Applies To: Windows PowerShell 2.0, Windows PowerShell 3.0, Windows PowerShell 5.0
>
> ## -Version `<Windows PowerShell Version>`
>
> Starts the specified version of Windows PowerShell. The version that you specify must be installed on the system. If Windows PowerShell 3.0 is installed on the computer, valid values are "2.0" and "3.0". The default value is "3.0".
>
> If Windows PowerShell 3.0 is not installed, the only valid value is "2.0". Other values are ignored.

Comment: @braintist When Powershell v4 is installed ,is it not expected to have powershell v3 also? It is windows 2012 R2 where Powershell v4 is available by default. So we will not install v3 then v4.

Comment: @Samselvaprabu powershell versions aren't cumulative. You only have 1 version installed. They offer starting in 2.0 compatibility mode, most likely because there were major language changes from 2 to 3. 2008 R2 == v2, 2012 == v3, 2012 R2 == v4 (as far as default versions go). You can't downgrade, but you can upgrade by installing a new version of Windows Management Framework (WMF).